# React Hooks / Fetching from API with Bearer Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I am building a React App, that fetches Data from an API, where a Bearer Token Authorization is required. Therefor I have `useState()` for both the Token and the Object I request, and aditionally 2 boolean `useState()` whether they have set values or not. It works all in the console when I change something in my code and refresh the page, but only then.

When I refresh a second time both auth and getting the object dont work anymore.

I suspect this is the case because of the `useEffect()`-Hook behaviour or asynchronous fetching but I cant figure out a working way

```
let batch_id = "XXX";

function App() {


const [objectOutput, setObjectOutput] = useState([]);
const [objectIsLoaded, setObjectIsLoaded] = useState([]);
const [authKey, setAuthKey] = useState([]);
const [authKeyIsSet, setAuthKeyIsSet] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    const authorize = async () => {
      var myHeaders = new Headers();
      myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

      var raw = JSON.stringify({
        username: "username",
        password: "password",
      });

      var requestOptions = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: myHeaders,
        body: raw,
        redirect: "follow"
      };

      const res = await fetch(api_url + "/auth", requestOptions).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      setAuthKey(data.token);
      setAuthKeyIsSet(true);
      console.log("Successful Authorization. Token: " + authKey);


  
    };

    authorize();

  }, [objectOutput]);



  useEffect(() => {
  const getObject = async () => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + authKey);

    console.log("Token in getObj:" + authKey);

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
      redirect: "follow"
    };

    const res = await fetch(api_url + "/get?function=readObject&args=" + batch_id, requestOptions).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
    const data = await res.json();

    setObjectOutput(data);
    setObjectIsLoaded(true);
    
    //Debugging Stuff
    console.log("###### ANALYSE in getObject() ########");      
    console.log("Key: " + authKey)
    console.log("KeyIsSet: " + authKeyIsSet)
    console.log("ObjectIsLoaded:" + objectIsLoaded)
    console.log(objectOutput); 
    console.log("###### ANALYSE in getObject() ########"); 
    
  };

  if(authKeyIsSet){
    getObject();
  }

}, [authKey]); 


  

  if(objectOutput === '' || objectOutput === undefined || typeof objectOutput === 'undefined' || !objectIsLoaded || !authKeyIsSet){
    return (<div>Loading</div>)
  }
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <Header
          title="Lorem Ipsum "
          description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
        />
        <Flagsection hasFlag={objectOutput.alarmFlag} />
        <Cardsection sort={objectOutput.attributes[5].value} treatment={objectOutput.attributes[11].value + " und " + objectOutput.attributes[12].value } plantheight={""} harvesttime={objectOutput.attributes[10].value} />
        <MapChart/>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );

}

export default App;
```

Comment: component state is not persist it's become after every refresh , you need to use localstorage to save your token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Borni.Mr said in their comment, use/setState isn't persistent, so storing the token in localStorage is a way to make it stay
then you just get or set the token eveytime it's needed or changed

this can be done with `localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(token));`
and to get it `const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"));`